# How to open multiple TGA files then save them compressed as 24 bits in Photoshop?

Tags: batch, adobe-photoshop, compression

I have a huge amount of TGA files from the game Counter-Strike (environment files such as sky, grass, water etc) and they are pretty big. There were some other TGA files that I manually opened and saved as (5.5MB total to 1.5MB) for weapon previews that I saved. This is for putting on my 256MB USB. I already removed the unwanted junk from the game. I just need a way to open up multiple TGA files, save them as the original name, save as 24 bit and "compressed" in photoshop. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://listoffreeware.com/list-of-best-free-bulk-image-converter/: many of them support TGA and PSD.

Answer (score 0):

I practically never use Adobe Photoshop, but from what I can tell only only jpeg, psd, and tiff are supported for batch conversions. Go to `File`, `Scripts`, and `Image Processing`, you'll get a screen like the picture below, which doesn't list tga. Support may vary by version, I'm using CS 5.5. Adobe Fireworks CS 5.5 doesn't support saving to TGA during batch conversions either.

[image: batch image processing]

Comment: Do you know any other Batch Image Processors that support TGA and have the compress option like Photoshop and the bits in Photoshop (16, 24, 36?) Counter-Strike doesn't support 16-bit TGA files.

Comment: You could ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com . ImageMagick may be able to do what you need, it's a terminal program, and I've never used it so I don't know what the required commands would be.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1QzUVZ5rBE
Windows->Operations->Create->[AnyName]
File->SaveAs->Choose format(in my situation tga)->Save
Targa Parameters->RLE
Operation(Window)->Stop
File->Automation->Batch Processing
Thats All!!!